# Intellij's "Language level" settings

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sdk, jvm

In Intellij IDE, in a Scala project, when I go to "Project Settings", I see two settings of "Language level".

One is under "Project", and the other is under "Modules".

**What do these "Language level" settings do, and what is the difference between them?**

**What would happen if I lowered each one of these "Language level" settings to a different level?**

In both settings, I was able to select a "Language level" which was lower than the selected (installed) SDK version. For example, SDK version is 18, but under "Project" I changed the "Language level" to 8.

**Does it mean that any of these "Language level" settings can make Intellij compile/run a project as if with an SDK of a version which is lower than the actual version of the selected (installed) SDK?**

Comment: See video by JetBrains: [*Helen’s take on project SDKs, Langual Level, and JDKs*](https://youtu.be/W4EK_KVgfkw)

Answer (score 1):

The language level for the module has a higher priority than the project's language level. In fact, project's language level is just a default value for module's language level.

In case of difference between configured SDK and language level, you will get all the in-editor inspections for the version of Java set in Language level, but the project will be compiled using the SDK defined in "SDK".

See JetBrains' video for more information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4EK_KVgfkw